# getting [object Object] instead of my jsx element in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

i want to add paragraph element to my div element on first mount .But on browser ,i see [object Object]. Also,i want to know why i am getting [object Object] on my browser instead of text 'hi' . what changes to be made for 'hi' text instead of [object Object].

```
import './App.css';
import {useEffect,useState} from  'react'

function App() {

  let h=(<p>hi</p>);
  useEffect(()=>{
   document.getElementById('i').append(h)
  },[])
  return (
    <div id='i' className="App">
     
 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use native DOM methods in React unless there's no other option.

Here, you should interpolate the `<p>` into the returned JSX. Use a boolean state to indicate whether the initial mount has completed.

```js
const { useEffect, useState} = React;

function App() {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
  useEffect(()=>{
    setMounted(true);
  },[])
  return (
    <div id='i' className="App">
     {
       mounted && <p>hi</p>
     }
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: but why am i getting [object Object] ??

Comment: Because you're mixing standard DOM methods with React, which you shouldn't do. `.innerHTML` accepts only a string of HTML - but your `p` variable is a JSX element - an object - which, when coerced to a string, is `[object Object]`.

Answer (score -1):

you are getting [object][object] because you are passing object in h.

You can change the code as below to get your desired output,

`let h='<p>hi</p>)';`

`document.getElementById("i").innerHTML += h`

Full code below,

```js
//import './App.css';
import React, {useEffect,useState} from  'react'

function App() {

  let h='<p>hi</p>)';
useEffect(()=>{
 document.getElementById("i").innerHTML +=  h
},[])
  return (
    <div id='i' className="App">
     
 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```